# Spring Batch. How to limit the no of executions of a chunk

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I started to use spring batch very recently. Can any body tell me how to limit the no of execution of a chunk (i.e. invocation of ItemReader and ItemWrite) within a tasklet.

I set the allow-start-if-complete="false", start-limit="1" in the tasklet. Then I set commit-interval="1" in the chunk.

```
<batch:step id="mig-chain-data">
<batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="false" start-limit="1">
<batch:chunk commit-interval="1" reader="reader" writer="writer"></batch:chunk>
</batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

My expectation is to run the tasklet/chunk only once for every batch job execution. But the behavior was the chunk(reader and writer) gets invoked several times/infinite.

Can anybody help me on this regards please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set max no of records read in flatfileItemReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771283/how-to-set-max-no-of-records-read-in-flatfileitemreader)

Comment: Look into [AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.setMaxItemCount()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html#setMaxItemCount-int-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of executions of a chunk depends on the `reader`; Spring Batch does not control it.
If your reader reads from a database table, this limit will be the number of records returned from your SQL statement, or if it reads from a file it will be the number of lines (in the very basic cases)

`start-limit` controls the number of times a Step may be started, not the chunk configured for this step.

Comment: @dharshan Did you solved it? Similar situation where I want to control the reader to read one line per job instance.

Answer (score 0):

add two parameters in your own reader:

```
private static int numberOfReading=0;
@Value("${batch.maxNumberOfReading}")
private int maxNumberOfReading;
```

and in the read method use this variable in order to control the flow:

```
if(numberOfReading<maxNumberOfReading){

   // do what do yoou have to do

   numberOfReading++;

   // return the result to the writer
}
return null;
```

batch.maxNumberOfReading is setted in the property file, with 1 as value