# How to set max no of records read in flatfileItemReader?

Tags: spring-batch

My application needs only fixed no of records to be read 
& processed. How to limit this if I am using a flatfileItemReader ? 
In DB based Item Reader, I am returning null/empty list when max_limit is reached.
How to achieve the same if I am using a org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader ?

Comment: Err, count them and stop when you've had enough?

Comment: Yes how to count them When an In-built FlatFileItemReader is used?

Comment: Per the answer below, `FlatFileItemReader` already allows you to specify `maxItemCount` out of the box, so you can just use that.

Answer (score 12):

For the `FlatFileItemReader` as well as any other `ItemReader` that extends [`AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html#setMaxItemCount-int-), there is a `maxItemCount` property.  By configuring this property, the `ItemReader` will continue to read until either one of the following conditions has been met:

1. The input has been exhausted.
2. The number of items read equals the `maxItemCount`.

In either of the two above conditions, null will be returned by the reader, indicating to Spring Batch that the input is complete.

If you have any custom `ItemReader` implementations that need to satisfy this requirement, I'd recommend extending the `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` and going from there.

Comment: Curiously, when I tried `reader.setMaxItemCount(10_000)` during test-run a job on my machine while reading from a deployed test-environment database, it resulted in the same 10,000 rows being written to the output file over and over again. Spring Batch v 4.1.1.Release

Answer (score 3):

The best approch is to write a delegate which is responsible to track down number of read records and stop after a fixed count; the components should take care of execution context to allow restartability

```
class CountMaxReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>,ItemStream
{
  private int count = 0;
  private int max = 0;
  private ItemReader<T> delegate;

  T read() {
    T next = null;
    if(count < max) {
      next = delegate.read();
      ++count;
    }
    return next;
  }

  void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    ((ItemStream)delegate).open(executionContext);
    count = executionContext.getInt('count', 0);
  }

  void close() {
    ((ItemStream)delegate).close(executionContext);
  }

  void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    ((ItemStream)delegate).update(executionContext);
    executionContext.putInt('count', count);
  }
}
```

This works with any reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CountMaxFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader {

    private int counter;

    private int maxCount;

    public void setMaxCount(int maxCount) {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object read() throws Exception {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= maxCount) {
            return null; // this will stop reading
        }
        return super.read();
    }
}
```

Something like this should work. The reader stops reading, as soon as null is returned.